# How to add a global parameter in Wordpress (ex : phone number)?

Tags: wordpress

I have disseminated in lot of posts and pages a contact phone number. But the best way would have been to define it somewhere only once (ideally in the admin interface) and to call it somehow like the site title.
Is it possible to achive this in Wordpress ? or do I have to change the contact phone number in every single post and page ...!

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: This depends on what you want. You can add a widget in the footer, you can modify the template file in PHP. You can create a plugin with a short code. There are a lot of possibilities of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Settings API: https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API to edit/display number on pages and Shortcode API to display in post: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

For example, put this in wp-content/plugins/phone.php:

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: Phone number
*/

add_action( 'admin_init', 'phone_settings_init' );

function phone_settings_init(  ) {
        register_setting( 'general', 'phone_number' );

        add_settings_field(
                'phone_field',
                'Phone field description',
                function() {
                        $phoneNumber = get_option( 'phone_number' );
                        ?>
                                <input type='text' name='phone_number' value='<?php echo $phoneNumber; ?>'>
                        <?php
                 },
                'general'
        );
}

// Add Shortcode
function phone_shortcode() {
        return get_option('phone_number');
}
add_shortcode( 'phone', 'phone_shortcode' );
```

Enable Phone number plugin in plugins page in WP Admin. On general settings page should appear new field where you can enter phone number (somewhere at the bottom). Fill it and save. After that you can display number on page by calling `<?php echo get_option('phone_number'); ?>` or on post page by shortcode (just put this on post page): [phone]